# Assigning strings to blocks and executing them in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

y:=3. z:=4.
h:= '[x:= y+z.]'.
(BlockClosure readFromString: h) value.

I have this code where I am trying to take a string in smalltalk syntax and trying to put it in a block and executing it but I am getting an error which says  :
Unhandled Exception: Message not understood #+

When I do comething like
h:= '[x:= 3+4.]'.
(BlockClosure readFromString: h) value

it works just fine. I don't understand why this is happening. I am guessing y is not pointing to anything and it does not understand the + method. But why is the block not treating y and z as free variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that y and z are not known in the context that actually compiles the string into a block.  You'd probably be better off with something like this:

```
h := '[ :y :z | x := y + z]'.
(BlockClosure readFromString: h) value: 3 value: 4.
```

Although I suspect that code probably won't work either - because x hasn't been declared anywhere, so a more correct version would be:

```
h := '[ :y :z | y + z]'.
x := (BlockClosure readFromString: h) value: 3 value: 4.
```

I don't think there's any real way you can make a String representation of a block act like a true closure in the context it's parsed, since it just won't have access to the variables - and would fail to compile.

Comment: THis is going to be such a pain in the ass for me. But I think your answer makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you really really need to do this, try the following:

```
   | x y z h block |
   y:=3. z:=4.
   h:= '[x:= y+z.]'.

   block := Compiler new
      evaluate: h
      in: thisContext
      allowReceiver: true
      receiver: self
      environment: self class environment
      notifying: nil
      ifFail: [self error: 'Failed to compile'].

   ^block value
```

I'd recommend, however, that you find a nicer way to solve the problem. Dynamically compiling strings in the context of a running method is really tricky and could be brittle.

Answer (score 1):

James Robertson recently posted to his [blog regarding Dynamic Code Generation](http://www.jarober.com/blog/blogView?showComments=true&printTitle=ST_4U_510%3a_Dynamic_Code_Generation_in_Pharo&entry=3565419024).
You may find it useful.